# Laravel migration generated a folder called db

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-7

After running `php artisan migrate` command successfully in a laravel 7.x project, I noticed a strange **db** folder in the root directory.
[image]

Is this normal? Why would this folder be generated?

Comment: Never seen this before. What does your `config/database.php` look like? Did you configure your system to use the `mysql` driver via `DB_CONNECTION=mysql` in `.env`? (I ask that as you have this question tagged with `mysql`)

Comment: This looks like database settings that are synced to docker.

Comment: @TimLewis yes I it's set to mysql `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),` and in the env file as well `DB_CONNECTION=mysql`

Comment: @benzo I do have docker on my laptop but it's currently not running. I also don't have any dockerfile in my project. So what triggered the creation of the db directory?

Comment: This looks alike a MySQL server data directory. While this question is probably rather pointless, unless providing the migration script, while may perform strange things. Is `db` a sym-link or are the files really in there?

Comment: @MartinZeitler how is the question pointless? I have over 30 migration files, should I share them? Like I stated, the migration ran without throwing an error. After that, I noticed the new db directory.

Comment: It is extremely pointless to present undesired behavior, but not the code which causes them. And honestly, if you ask "why would this folder be generated" ... I'd assume, that is because you run scripts without knowing what they actually do. It's no problem to open 30 files at once in an IDE; one of them might install MySQL into the web-server's root.

Comment: I understand your point. However in this case it would a lot of code to post. Only one command was ran which was the migrate command so I have been careful to run scripts that I know exactly what they do.